# Windows Findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, findstr

I'm trying to find files in a folder with specific pattern like:

> **abcd201 abcd001 abcd004**

The folder contains files named

```
abcd(3 numbers)
```

I'm trying to use the pattern:

`abcd[0,2][0][1,4]` but currently not working.

```
DIR /b C:\Folder\abcd"[0,2][0][1,4]".txt
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir` command does not support regular expressions. You need to filter the output with findstr

```
dir /b "c:\folder\abcd*.txt" | findstr /r /c:"^abcd[02]0[14]\.txt$"
```

That is, use dir command to obtain a first approximation of what you are searching and then filter the list (pipe the `dir` command to `findstr`) to obtain only the list of required files.

The regular expression (`/r`) in `findstr` means: filter the lines, starting at the start of the line (initial `^`), followed by `abcd`, followed by any character in the set `[02]`, followed by a `0`, followed by any character in the set `[14]`, followed by a dot (a single dot means any character, so, it needs to be escaped `\.`), followed by the string `txt` and the end of the line (`$`).

Maybe you will need to add a `/i` switch to findstr to indicate it must ignore case when matching.

Answer (score 0):

The regex of your example would also match `abcd204` name. You may find these 4 files in a simpler way:

```
for %a in (0 2) do for %c in (1 4) do dir /B C:\Folder\abcd%a0%c.txt 2>NUL
```

This method is faster than findstr's one, especially if the number of files is large.